# GITLAB : Promote subgroup milestone to group milestone

Tags: gitlab

I have a group with some subgroups, and i have create a milestone in one of those subgroups, is there a way to promote this milestone from a subgroup to its parent group so i can assign an issue created in any of the subgroups to this milestone?